# How can I fix the normals in this instanced lighting example? (Monogame/XNA)

Tags: xna, monogame, hlsl

The models in my game are instanced to reduce draw calls, which basically means I'm passing in a 4x4 transform as part of a custom vertex definition. I am trying to get basic lighting working but can't seem to get the normals calculations working. It seems that no matter what I try, only the top of models are lit, regardless of the position of the sun.

Furthermore, I also can't get any of the lights other than the sun to even show up. I'm thinking I'm maybe missing a transform somewhere.

```
float4x4 World;
float4x4 View;
float4x4 Projection;


#define MAXLIGHT 20

float3 PointLightPosition[MAXLIGHT];
float4 PointLightColor[MAXLIGHT];
float PointLightIntensity[MAXLIGHT];
float PointLightRadius[MAXLIGHT];
int MaxLightsRendered = 0;
struct VS_MODEL_ShaderInput
{
    float4 Position : SV_Position;
    float4 Color : COLOR;
    float2 TexCoord : TEXCOORD0;
    float3 Normal : NORMAL;
    
};
struct VertexShaderOutput
{
    float4 Position : SV_Position;
    float4 WorldPosition : COLOR1;
    
    float3 Normal : TEXCOORD1;
    float2 TexCoord : TEXCOORD0;
    float4 Color : COLOR;
    
};
float4 CalcDiffuseLight(float3 normal, float3 lightDirection, float4 lightColor, float lightIntensity)
{

    return saturate(dot(normal, -lightDirection)) * lightIntensity * lightColor;
}

float4 CalcSpecularLight(float3 normal, float3 lightDirection, float3 cameraDirection, float4 lightColor, float lightIntensity)
{
    float3 halfVector = normalize(-lightDirection + -cameraDirection);
    float specular = saturate(dot(halfVector, normal));

    //I have all models be the same reflectance
    float specularPower = 20;

    return lightIntensity * lightColor * pow(abs(specular), specularPower);
}

// The squared length of a vector
float lengthSquared(float3 v1)
{
    return v1.x * v1.x + v1.y * v1.y + v1.z * v1.z;
}

float3 CameraPosition;
float3 SunLightDirection;
float4 SunLightColor;
float SunLightIntensity;





Texture2D Texture;
sampler textureSampler = sampler_state
{
    Texture = <Texture>;
    MinFilter = linear;
    MagFilter = Anisotropic;
    AddressU = Wrap;
    AddressV = Wrap;
};




VertexShaderOutput Model_InstancingVS(VS_MODEL_ShaderInput input, float4x4 instanceTransform : BLENDWEIGHT)
{
    instanceTransform = mul(World, transpose(instanceTransform));
    VertexShaderOutput output;

    // Apply the world and camera matrices to compute the output position.
    float4 worldPosition = mul(input.Position, instanceTransform);
    float4 viewPosition = mul(worldPosition, View);
    output.Position = mul(viewPosition, Projection);
    output.WorldPosition = (float4) worldPosition;
    output.Normal = normalize(mul(input.Normal, (float3x3) instanceTransform));
    // Compute lighting, using a simple Lambert model.
    
    output.Color = input.Color;

    // Copy across the input texture coordinate.
    output.TexCoord = input.TexCoord;

    return output;


}
float4 MainPS(VertexShaderOutput input) : COLOR0
{

    float4 outColor = tex2D(textureSampler, input.TexCoord); // * output.Color;
    float4 diffuseLight = float4(0, 0, 0, 0);
    float4 specularLight = float4(0, 0, 0, 0);
    float4 diffuseSpecular = float4(0, 0, 0, 0);
    
    float3 cameraDirection = normalize((float3) input.WorldPosition - CameraPosition);
    diffuseLight += CalcDiffuseLight(input.Normal, SunLightDirection, SunLightColor, SunLightIntensity);
    diffuseSpecular += CalcSpecularLight(input.Normal, SunLightDirection, cameraDirection, SunLightColor, SunLightIntensity);

    
    //return outColor;
    
    
////calculate our pointLights
    [loop]
    for (int i = 0; i < MaxLightsRendered; i++) 
    {
        float3 PointLightDirection = (float3) input.WorldPosition - PointLightPosition[i];
                           
        float DistanceSq = lengthSquared(PointLightDirection);

        float radius = PointLightRadius[i];
             
        [branch]
        if (DistanceSq < abs(radius * radius))
        {
            float Distance = sqrt(DistanceSq);

            PointLightDirection /= Distance;

            float du = Distance / (1.0 - DistanceSq / (radius * radius - 1));

            float denom = du / abs(radius) + 1.0;

            //The attenuation is the falloff of the light depending on distance basically
            float attenuation = 1.0 / (denom * denom);

            diffuseLight += CalcDiffuseLight(input.Normal, PointLightDirection, PointLightColor[i], PointLightIntensity[i]) * attenuation;
            
            specularLight += CalcSpecularLight(input.Normal, PointLightDirection, cameraDirection, PointLightColor[i], PointLightIntensity[i]) * attenuation;
        }
    }
    
    return outColor * diffuseLight * diffuseSpecular;

}



technique ModelInstancing
{
    pass P0
    {
        VertexShader = compile vs_3_0 Model_InstancingVS();
        PixelShader = compile PS_SHADERMODEL MainPS();
    }
};
```

If anyone can spot anything or give me a shove in the right direction I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: This is a tough one. Have you made any progress? With a shader of this size, it is hard to say what might cause a bug. I can't find anything obvious while skimming over it. Is all data sent to the shader correctly? (light data, the meshes etc.) Are the mesh normals read correctly? Here, it might be best to reduce the complexity of the shader again until it works as expected and then add part by part while keeping sure it still works. E.g. first drawing face normals of the meshes (as color) without any lighting to see if they're correct, then sunlight only, then a single light source only etc.

Comment: Small possible tests: in the lambert model:'saturate(dot(normal, -lightDirection))' the light direction is usually positive. Also, you said "the position of the sun", I'm sure you meant direction of the sun (as it is a directional light - so no position, just a direction vector), correct?

Comment: thanks for the comment, I figured it out, it was addition for specular and diffuse, not multiplication lol

Comment: Oh yes absolutely, good catch! Nothing better than such a bug as I usually spend a whole day looking for it while losing all hope :D

Answer (score 0):

diffuseLight * diffuseSpecular needed to be addition:

diffuseLight + diffuseSpecular